# Pre installed Windows XP not working on different PC

Tags: windows-xp

I have upgraded a PC's Motherboard from Intel D845 to D915 Intel,now the OS was Windows XP not working on upgraded PC.I do upgrade PCs frequently and repair the OS all the time,help me if any quick solution is available.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more info?  What do you mean its "not working"?  Does it throw errors on bootup?  Does it not boot at all?  Does the bios screen load OK?  How far do you get?

Comment: every thing goes well,but soon before appearing welcome screen, it restarts un-expectedly(without any error).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you can prepare Windows for a change of hardware by running the `Sysprep` program with generalise, however by default, Windows ties itself to your hardware.

You can usually add or change insignificant components without breaking anything, but something serious like a motherboard will usually cause problems. I have only had luck on a few occasions where it was the same chipset on the new motherboard.

Your best bet is to do a repair installation or a complete reinstall, it really comes down to your preference.

(There are a few good tools that allow you to migrate / backup and restore to different hardware, but I am not aware of any free tools that do this).

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair the installation when you replace a motherboard with a different model, scroll down to "Replace a failed Motherboard"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824125

Comment: Please read the question carefully !!

Comment: I did, please explain better by editing your original question. -1